# Docx4j DrawingML and VML (docx to PDF)

Tags: pdf, docx, docx4j

I am a bit new to Docx4j and "wordML".

I want to convert this docx to a pdf :

[image]

But my research showed me that drawingML and VML wasn't supported, at least yet.

like : http://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/drawingml-vml-to-pdf-t949.html

Is it true ? Is there a way out of this problem with Docx4j or should I think of using another technology ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, docx4j’s PDF output is suitable for documents which contain paragraphs, tables and images. It can’t handle more exotic features, such as equations, SmartArt, or WordArt (DrawingML or VML).

source : http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.pdf

I used the openoffice api : https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-convert-docxodt-to-pdfhtml-with-java/

For who it may concern !!!